# Eclipse on ubuntu can't resolve simple libraries like stdio

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I used the following code code and it gave me this warning: "Unresolved inclusion <stdio.h>"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

I tried reseting eclipse, add path like "\usr\includes".

Comment: There is obviously something wrong with your project configuration. There are several ways to configure a C project. How exactly does the project need to be configured to reproduce your issue? Please link to the tutorial or documentation that you followed. What do you mean exactly by _'I tried reseting eclipse, add path like "\usr\includes"'_ (it's unclear what you exactly did)?

Comment: On my computer, the self-installed compiler has a "/usr/include" directory (without a plural s at the end). And with forward slashes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdio is a standard header file that would be installed into `/usr/include` on a standard Ubuntu install.  This location is normally within the `$PATH` environment variable and would normally be picked up by default (well, at least it has on my installs...).

Make sure `/usr/include` is in the library search path within the Eclipse project settings.  You have stated `\usr\includes` in your question which isn't correct, both in format and in name.

Once you have `/usr/include` in the search path, if it still fails then go to a terminal window and type:

```
find /usr/include/ -name "stdio.h"
```

If it's not there, you need to install/reinstall build-essentials with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

Comment: No, it is not in the `$PATH` in any reasonable configuration (only directories with executable programs are).